# Как связывать товары в woocommerce разных размеров?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Суть следующая - в woo создаётся несколько товаров разных размеров (вариации одного товара не подойдут, должны быть именно разные товары). Как можно связать двусторонне товары, чтобы можно было на странице каждого из связанных товаров выбрать размер? К примеру, выбираем размер - открывается товар с другим размером.

Comment: Почему это вариации не подойдут? Это как раз про них. Каждая вариация  это по сути и есть  отдельный товар. (а то что ты придумал - какая-то хрень несуветная, кмк)

Comment: Вариации делаются на атрибутах, где это отдельный товар?)

Comment: В базе как минимум.